# Angular ABN tree: how to select an element from code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [ABN tree](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/) and I would like to select a particular element from code, primarily so I can implement a search function.

I tried setting the "selected" property on the relevant element. This only partially works: the element is selected, but when the user clicks on another element, it doesn't become deselected.

In the source I see there is a select_branch function internal to ABN tree. However, I haven't figured out how to access this from outside - I can't get a reference to the scope.

So, how can I do this? I'm open minded to using a different tree control.

Comment: are you still working with abn tree?

Comment: @Batman - no, we ditched ABan tree in the end

Comment: Did you find something else you think works well? Seems like there aren't many options.

Answer (score 1):

You can add select-text attribute to the abntree and bind select-text to a model. e.g.

```
<abn-tree tree-data="my_data" on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" select-text="textToSelect"></abn-tree>
```

In the tree directive, add selectText entry to your scope. Your scope will therefore be

```
scope: {
    treeData: '=',
    onSelect: '&',
    initialSelection: '@',
    selectText: '=',
    treeControl: '='
  },
```

Then just before the return statement in the directive, add the following code

```
scope.$watch('selectText', function() {
    if (scope.selectText) {
      for_each_branch(function (b) {
        if (b.label === scope.selectText) {
          return select_branch(b);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Now set the model's text to the value you want and it should select it in the tree and call any select handler you might have set on the tree.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the above code (maybe with this version of abn-tree that code failed ), with this changes you can select a node by id or by by title .hope it helps :)

in abn_tree source js file change scope to this :

```
 scope: {
              treeData: '=',
              onSelect: '&',
              onDblSelect: '&',
              initialSelection: '=',
              selectedText: '=',//parichehr
              selectedId: '=',//parichehr
              treeControl: '=',
              labelFiled: '=',
              idFiled: '=',//parichehr
              childrenField: '='
          },
```

then add this part bellow link:function...

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

              scope.label = scope.labelFiled || 'Title';
              scope.id = scope.idFiled || 'Id';//parichehr
              scope.children = scope.childrenField || 'Children';
```

then add this part bellow TreeDataWatcher...:

```
  var treeDataWatcher = scope.$watch('treeData', onTreeDataChange, true);
              //parichehr start
              var selectedTextWatcher = scope.$watch('selectedText', function () {
                  if (scope.selectedText) {
                      forEachBranch(function (b) {
                          if (b[scope.label] === scope.selectedText) {
                              return selectBranch(b);
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
              var selectedIdWatcher = scope.$watch('selectedId', function () {
                  if (scope.selectedId) {
                      forEachBranch(function (b) {
                          if (b[scope.id] === scope.selectedId) {
                              return selectBranch(b);
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
              //parichehr end
```

finally dispose the watchers at the end:

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                  if (treeDataWatcher) treeDataWatcher();
                  if (initialWatcher) initialWatcher();
                  //parichehr start
                  if (selectedTextWatcher) selectedTextWatcher();
                  if (selectedIdWatcher) selectedIdWatcher();
                  //parichehr end
              });
```

in your html you will have this changes:
if you want to select by node title :

```
<abn-tree tree-data="my_data" on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" selected-text="textToSelect"></abn-tree>
```

and if you want to select by node id:

```
<abn-tree tree-data="my_data" on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" selected-id="idToSelect"></abn-tree>
```